# Correct way of changing svg image in svelte

Tags: image, svg, svelte, sveltekit

In svelte, I have the option of switching between two images, or using css to change the color of the svg image. Which is "better/ best practice"? (also we use tailwind css).

```
    <div class='w-2 h-2'>
     {#if condition}
      <Image1/>  <--white image
     {:else}
      <Image2/>  <--red image
     {/if}
    </div>
```

OR
If the default image is white, this passes red to it. The color variable would be text-red or text-white based on some condition.

```
    <div class='w-2 h-2 ${color}'> 
      <Image1/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Svelte's reactivity can take over colour conditions via CSS. We can avoid the if condition.

App.svelte

```html
<script>
import Icon from "./Icon.svelte"

let stroke = "green";

function changeStroke(){
    stroke = "red"
}

</script>

<Icon {stroke}/>

<button on:click={changeStroke}>Change</button>
```

Icon.svelte

```html
<script>
export let stroke = 'white';
</script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" {stroke} stroke-width="2">
  <!-- Big SVG -->
</svg>
```

See this example [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2484abbea6db444da389142647316de4?version=3.49.0)

Comment: Thanks for the REPL link at the end of the answer to see it in action. That was helpful